# how to convert flash embed to html5 ? 

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, jwplayer

Where is the RTMP live stream `Link` in the following `Embed` and how can i test the link and see if it is working or not

[image]

i thought it could be this but not sure

```
 rtmp://sc-lb1.streamcyclone.com/rakoty_live
```

beacsue i'm play this stream using `jwplayer` and it keeps telling me

```
stream not found :rtmp://--------------------
```

here is my code so far and a [Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/u92Az/1/)

```
    <div id="container2">Loading the player...</div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
             jwplayer("container2").setup({
             flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
             height: 270,
             width: 480,
             image: "http://www.2heartsnetwork.org/SacredHeartJesus3.jpg",
             levels: [
{ bitrate: 300, file: "rtmp://sc-lb1.streamcyclone.com/rakoty_live", width: 320 },
{ bitrate: 600, file: "rtmp://sc-lb1.streamcyclone.com/rakoty_live", width: 480 },
{ bitrate: 900, file: "rtmp://sc-lb1.streamcyclone.com/rakoty_live", width: 720 }
                 ],
             provider: "rtmp",
         streamer: "rtmp://sc-lb1.streamcyclone.com/rakoty_live"
      });
       </script>
```

there is something wrong i hope you guys can help me 
thanks

**ANSWER**

There is no way to do this with out a third party to transcode your stream

Comment: Are you sure jwplayer supports rtmp?

Comment: it doesn't .. the only two options i have is using a third party like wawza and pay $55/month or use VLC -or similar- to transcode the stream as a server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/270634/how-can-i-verify-that-an-rtmp-stream-url-is-working), You may use [rtmpdump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/), to test a rtmp connection.

---

Fiddling with what you shared, I was able to get your live stream by setting :

```
file : "rakoty"
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u92Az/3/) is the running fiddle.

---

I would also like to suggest not to edit you post & remove the original question when it is answered, rather post a new one. Perhaps the earlier question could have been helpful to someone in future...

Answer (score 0):

You have 
streamer: rtmp://sc-lb1.streamcyclone.com/rakoty_live
file: rakoty

rtmpdump -o a.flv -r rtmp://sc-lb1.streamcyclone.com/rakoty_live/rakoty